# python & pandas: subset dataframe with value in a list

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe `df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3,4],'B':['G','H','I','K']})` and I want to select rows where the value of column A is in [2,3]

To do this, I write a simple for-loop: `df.loc[[ e in [2,3] for e in df.A],]`

Is there any build-in function that can do this instead of using for-loops?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

you just pronounced it!

```
df[df.A.isin([2,3])]
   A  B
1  2  H
2  3  I
```

so it selects rows (`df[...]`) where a value of A (`df.A`) is in a given list (`.isin([2,3])`)

Comment: isin() function is so useful! thanks

Comment: what about if you need to check two columns?

Comment: @Ali.E, docs give an example of how to do this https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html and also how to do is not in.